# Ditaa and the right-to-left issue of rendering

Tags: emacs, drawing, org-mode, right-to-left

Consider the below MWE:

**MWE**

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ditaa :file "./MWE_ditaa.png" :cmdline -r


                                                   +-------------------------+
                                               |      المستوى الاول      |
                                                   |                         |
                                                   +------------+------------+
                                |
                                        v
                                                   +------------+------------+
                           |     المستوى الثاني      |
                           |                 |
                                                   +------------+------------+
                                |
                                 +------------------------------*------------------------------+
                                 |                              |                              |
                                 v                              v                              v
                    +------------+------------+    +------------+------------+    +------------+------------+
                    |                         |    |                         |    |                         |
                    |        يمين             |    |            وسط          |    |            يسار         |     
                    |                         |    |                         |    |                         |
                    +------------+------------+    +------------+------------+    +------------+------------+


#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
[[file:./MWE_ditaa.png]]
```

**Output**

[image]

So the problem in rendering is that the left became right and vice versa.

Is there any solution to this problem?

**Notes**

- including any English text will render the right and left rectangles correctly. This direction issue pops up only when Right-to-left language is used (here Arabic).
- ditaa version 0.9
- Org mode version 9.0.5
- I use Droid Sans Mono-10 for Arabic font (other fonts can lead to a messy rendering of ditaa figures)